# The type name FromFile does not exist in the type Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D

Tags: c#, xna

I was trying to use this well documented function with visual studios 2010 and xna 4.0 and get the error:

The type name FromFile does not exist in the type Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Texture2D

With this code:

```
Texture2D tex1 = Texture2D.FromFile(device, "1.bmp");
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Texture2D.FromFile` is a static method that returns you a texture.  Your `new` makes C# look for a type called `Texture2D.FromFile` (that is, a class inside `Texture2D` called `FromFile`).

Drop the `new`.

EDIT:  Seems 4.0 doesn't have `Texture2D.FromFile` at all.  The closest match i see is `Texture2D.FromStream`, where you'd pass it an open stream to your file rather than its name.

Comment: Good observation, I actually just copied a piece of code from online and pasted it into my project and altered just for an example to put on here.  However, I  made the appropriate alterations and it still does not work.... I right clicked on the Texture2d and the function I am looking for is not defined; this makes me think that it was made obsolete for some other method.  Any comments from those knowledgeable about xna?

Comment: I'm seeing little notes above the docs for the method that say it's only available when you're coding for Windows.  Does this make a difference (ie: are you writing for another platform)?

Comment: Yup, strictly a windows program.